# Why ci" and ci(, ci{.... behave differently?

Tags: vim

we all know what `ci"` `ci'` `ci(` `ci[` ... does. Very handy in everyday's editing.  I found something strange, and checked the help, didn't find out why.

say, I have a file:

```
foo "target"
foo 'target'
foo (target)
foo {target}
foo [target]
foo <target>
```

if my cursor at the **beginning** of each line, (on the '`f`'), then I type ci", ci', ci(...

the `cix` works only with quotes (single or double), doesn't work for brackets. why do they behave differently?

(`dix`, `vix` the same)

tested with --noplugin, vim 7.3

thank you.

**Update**

thanks @romainl for the answer. I still have doubt regarding the "pair processing in vim"

check this example:

```
foo "targ\"eti\" some\"thing else "
```

if I have a line like above, I type `ci"`, no matter cursor is at beginning or between quotes, it works perfectly, it seems that vim does have the idea of "pair"?

and this maybe what you meant about the pairing ?

```
foo "target x some"thing else "
foo (target x some(thing else )
```

I have above two lines, if (cursor at `x`) I type `ci"` and `ci(`, nothing happened to 2nd line, but first line changed into:

```
foo "I"thing else " (I is cursor)
```

Comment: Vim doesn't pair quotes. The heuristic it uses is really very simple: Scan leftwards to find a `'` or `"`. Repeat rightwards if there's no hit. Then repeat rightwards again to find the closing quote. Escaped quotes `\'` `\"` are never taken into account.

Comment: See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7804666/254635) to the question "[Selecting text inside paranthesis from outside the parenthesis in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7803905/254635)".

Comment: @ib. and glts, thx for the comments. upvote!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

***2023 edit***

Today I was reminded of this answer by an upvote and it must be said that all the text objects mentioned in this Q&A work the same, now: if you are outside of a pair of parentheses or a pair of quotes, the next pair will be operated on.

The change happened some time between 8.1 and 9.0 but I can't find the exact version.

***end of 2023 edit***

`ci(` is consistent with `ci[`, `ci{` and `cit` and all the other `<action>i<something>`. Only `ci'` and `ci"` work like they do. The outliers are the quotes, here, not the brackets.

Vim doesn't consider that quotes come in pairs while brackets do. It has an internal logic for matching pairs that works with actual pairs but not with quotes hence the difference in behavior.

You are not the first to complain about that discrepancy: [this is one solution](https://gist.github.com/1171559), maybe you can find others.

***edit***

I don't have a deep knowledge of Vim's internals, unfortunately, so I can only make assumptions, here.

If you ask Vim to do `ci"` it does its best to find a pair of double quotes but double quotes don't go by pairs: there's no way to tell if a `"` is the closing one or the opening one contrary to brackets. Because of that, Vim must make some choices. IMO, the choice that would make the most sense considering how the other members of the family work, would be to assume that the cursor is between the quotes and select from the first one to the right to the first one to the left. I can only assume that this method proved wrong in some way or didn't work for some reason and that the other method (the current one) prevailed.

Another explanation could be that the `i<something>` mechanism is somehow tied to a specific subsystem (maybe the same as `showmatch`?) that is unable to deal correctly with quotes.

Anyway, just like you, I find this discrepancy weird and I've somehow internalized it and aligned my usage of `<action>i"` to how the others work. To the point of actually doing `2t"ci"` or some variant instead of `ci"`!! Inefficient, I know.

Did you read `:h a'`? I completely forgot where I got my "limited understanding" of the issue but it was there! It says:

> "Only works within one line. When the cursor starts on a quote, Vim will figure out which quote pairs form a string by searching from the start of the line."

What I get from that is this: for some reasons unknown to us, Vim uses another mechanism for matching quotes than for the other pairs and that is why `ci"` is different from `cib`and friends. The underlying cause is not clear at all but I'm fairly certain that the big picture looks a lot like what I imagine.

To me, it looks a lot like a bug or a limitation disguised as a feature.

If you are still curious, I'd suggest you ask any further question on [vim-dev](http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim-dev).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I still have some doubts, I update the question, to get better format supports. can you pls take a look? thx.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! I will make some mapping in my .vimrc to try to make them behave same. answer accepted!

Comment: Part of the reason, I think, is that brackets (), {}, [], <>, etc. all nest. Quotes don't nest; and in C-like languages quotes rarely can cross line boundaries easily. Rather than have a useless search when the cursor is not within quotes Vim decided to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

make use of `%`

```
" nnoremap cb cib
nnoremap cb %cib
" nnoremap vb vib
nnoremap vb %vib
nnoremap yb %yib
nnoremap db %dab
```

to enhance `%`:
https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup#tocbar-dopjfd

`b` can match `(` `[` `{`,
Want to use `'` to match both `'` and `"`?

```
nnoremap c' :call DoubleAsSingleC()<CR>
func! DoubleAsSingleC()
    " When [!] is added, error messages will also be skipped,
    " and commands and mappings will not be aborted
    " when an error is detected.  |v:errmsg| is still set.
    let v:errmsg = ""
    silent! :s#\"\([^"]*\)\"#'\1'#g
    if (v:errmsg == "")
        echo "双变单"
    endif

    exec "normal ci'"
endfunc
```

Similar for:
`d'`
`y'`
`v'`

Comment: Thanks for sharing this though it doesn't really answer the "why" question.

Comment: Could you please explain your solution, what it does and why it does what it does? Some of us are newer to Vim (or use vim through VSC).