# Choosing the second object in a line in vim

Tags: vim

When I have a line like the following, I can visual select everything in the first quotes with `vi"`.

```
if foo == "bar" and bar == "foo":
```

Is there a way in vim how I can visual select **foo** instead of **bar** by also using something like `vi`?

Comment: Move the cursor so that it is in foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do it like `f";;vi"`.

Answer (score 2):

No faster way, you have to move to the target `"foo"` then do `vi"`.

the `"bar"` could be selected when you are at the beginning of the line ( or before the `"bar"`). because `"` is not "paired characters".

E.g. when your cursor on `and`, do a `vi"`, you will select `and bar ==` which is not what you expected.

So you have to move your cursor to the target `"foo"`

P.S, I have ever asked a question some time ago here, you may want to take a look:

[Why ci" and ci(, ci{.... behave differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650788/why-ci-and-ci-ci-behave-differently)

Answer (score 2):

From [this gist by Steve Losh](https://gist.github.com/sjl/1171642) (there are other versions):

```
" Motion for "next/last object". For example, "din(" would go to the next "()" pair
" and delete its contents.

onoremap an :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 'f')<cr>
xnoremap an :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 'f')<cr>
onoremap in :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 'f')<cr>
xnoremap in :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 'f')<cr>

onoremap al :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 'F')<cr>
xnoremap al :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a', 'F')<cr>
onoremap il :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 'F')<cr>
xnoremap il :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i', 'F')<cr>

function! s:NextTextObject(motion, dir)
  let c = nr2char(getchar())

  if c ==# "b"
      let c = "("
  elseif c ==# "B"
      let c = "{"
  elseif c ==# "d"
      let c = "["
  endif

  exe "normal! ".a:dir.c."v".a:motion.c
endfunction
```