# How can I directly select text within parantheses in vim when cursor is outside them?

Tags: vim

on the next sentence for instance,

```
---> delete character under the cursor (short for "dl")
```

when my cursor is at the very start, `vi"` directly selects `dl`

However, the same does not apply when I enter `vi(`

it only works when I move the cursor on top of `(`, like `f(`

is this the nature of vim or am I missing something??

Comment: What version of Vim do you use? That [long lasting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651443/546861) discrepancy as been fixed in 8.2.3255.

Comment: Thank you! I updated gVim to 9.0 and it works!

Answer (score -1):

Here in neovim 0.8 if I type `vi(` it will jump and start visual selection as you want.