# Changing text inside parenthesis that appear later in the current line

Tags: vim

Often times I want to change the text inside a parenthesis. If my cursor is at the beginning of the line:

```
String result = callMethod("someString");
```

I need to first move it inside the parenthesis

```
String result = callMethod("someString");
```

before I can type `ci(` to replace the text:

```
String result = callMethod();
```

However, I've noticed that when changing the text inside quotes, I don't need to move the cursor first.

```
String result = callMethod("someString");
```

And then type `ci"`, and the cursor will jump forward to the first set of quotes on the line, clearing its contents:

```
String result = callMethod("");
```

Is it possible to enjoy this same functionality with parenthesis?

Comment: Related questions on SO: [Why ci" and ci(, ci{… behave differently?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14650788/1121933) and [Selecting text inside paranthesis from outside the parenthesis in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7803905/1121933)

Comment: Related question on [Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) site: [Why does ci" and ci( behave differently?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/19/6698)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quotes and single quotes work by default the way you're describing.

Try the plugin https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim to make it work with parenthesis etc. This plugin adds some more text objects too.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't realize it works for quotes. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option. Add the following code to your .vimrc file

```
    onoremap in( :<c-u>execute "normal! /(\rvi("<cr>
    onoremap il( :<c-u>execute "normal! ?)\rvi("<cr>
    onoremap in{ :<c-u>execute "normal! /{\rvi("<cr>
    onoremap il{ :<c-u>execute "normal! ?}\rvi("<cr>
```

Then you can just type `cin(` to replace the text inside the next pair of parentheses. You could also do `cil(` to replace inside the most recent pair of parentheses (`n` for "next" and `l` for "last"). As you see I've also got this set to work with braces, and one could also do square brackets, quotes, etc. Since this is an operator map I can also type `din(` if I just want to delete the text without replacing it, or any other operation that acts on a range of text.

I first learned this mapping in this tutorial: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/, which I highly recommend.